# Google Contacts API is throwing unauthorized exception from C# Winform

Tags: c#, winforms, google-api, google-api-client, google-contacts-api

I am working to get Gmail contacts of an user.

Problem Scenario : User will be authenticated via Oauth2 and then windows client ( C#) will get all contacts for that authenticated user and display them in a list box. API to use : https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/

Current Solution ( not working yet) : https://github.com/dnemai/GoogleContactsFromWinApp

I believe I am doing authorization properly because I am receiving data from another API ( GetUserInfo).

I was hoping that the same approach will work to get contacts . But , GetContacts method ( in my solution ) is throwing invalid authorization error.

I spent almost 2 days on this but could not figure out what is going wrong. Is it my code or is it google API who is doing something wrong?

Would you be able to help me on this?

Comment: Got the solution. Uploaded at : https://github.com/dnemai/GetGoogleContacts

Answer (score -1):

Two issues are possible in my view:

1. the client secret information is not proper
2. the refresh token is not created

```
if (credential.Token.IsExpired(credential.Flow.Clock))
{
   if (credential.RefreshTokenAsync(CancellationToken.None).Result)
   {
      ...
   }
}
```

Hopefuly this helps.

Andreas